# Iframe back cause main window back

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

here is my code:

```
<iframe id="ifr" src="https://www.wikipedia.org/" frameborder="0"></iframe>
<script>
  var ifr = document.querySelector("#ifr")
  ifr.src = "http://bing.com"
  ifr.contentWindow.history.back()
</script>
```

I expect the result is wikipedia.org, but when i open a new tab in chrome, and type `/home/roroco/Dropbox/jss/ro-js/ex/test-iframe-back.html`, it show "new tab", it means the main window is back

[image]

how to avoid main window go back

Comment: why are you using `ifr.contentWindow.history.back()` ? it's going back because of it.

Comment: I hope implement a button to make iframe go back

Answer (score 0):

If you have the "Back Button" inside your iFrame.html page, you have to use:

```
window.history.back();
```

instead of :

```
ifr.contentWindow.history.back();
```

in your html file, add:

```
<input type="button" onClick="GoBack();">
```

and in your JavaScript file, add:

```
function GoBack() {
window.history.back();
}
```

and you can use:

```
parent.history.back();
```

inside iFrame to go back the parent of iFrame.

Comment: I don' completely understand, If I  wanna iframe back but main window don't back, how should i run `window.history.back()` in iframe?

Comment: You have an html file that you use it as "src" attribute for your iFrame. so you have to add an <input type="button" onClick="Goback();"> to your html file and in java script create a function named "GoBack" and write the code in the function.